# How to connect an iPad to a digital projector

Tags: ipad

What do I need in order to connect an iPad to a digital projector?  I have tried nothing, because I have no idea what to try.

Comment: Do you have the digital projector already? if yes, what type of plug does it have?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually very simple. 
You just need the right cable.

Depending on Projector type you might use the [Lightning to VGA Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD825ZM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter) if your Projector is of that type. Note: it does not support Audio!.
Look at your Projector to see if the plug looks like this:

[image]

If your projector has HDMI plug use the [Lightning Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD826ZM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter)

Look at your projector if the plug looks like this:
[image]

The projectors normally have 16:9 = wide screen (for movies) and you iPad does not, so you will see a black stripe on both sides, that is normal.

PS: if it has both plugs pick the second one "Lightning Digital AV Adapter" since you can use it to plug in to your LCD TV :)